# C# 7.0 language features compile error on .Net 4.x

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I have a project that uses *.Net 4.0.* (the target framework is .Net 4).

I use Visual Studio 2017 to compile the source, and used the following code:

```
if(int.TryParse(inputText, out int x))
   StartAnotherMethod(x);
```

It successfuly compiled on my computer so I commited it to the repository and waited for the build server to compile as well.

Surprisingly, it had compilation errors.

> error CS1525: Invalid expression term 'int'
>
> error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected

I checked it in an online compiler. It uses .Net 4.5, and *also shows compilation errors*.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/pibxC2

> Compilation error (line 9, col 32): Invalid expression term 'int'
>
> Compilation error (line 9, col 33): ; expected
>
> Compilation error (line 9, col 33): Invalid expression term ')'
>
> Compilation error (line 9, col 34): ; expected
>
> Compilation error (line 9, col 34): Invalid expression term ')'
>
> Compilation error (line 9, col 35): ; expected

As I have read, *language features* don't require new frameworks, so it should compile without any problem.

What did I miss?

Comment: You aren't using a compiler for C# 7.  Change the compiler to Roslyn.

Comment: Which compiler is used by your build-server? You need the Compiler of the VisualStudio 2017 to compile your project.

Comment: What compiler is your build server using?  These features depend on the version of the compiler, not the version of the framework.

Comment: Have you done something like this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/enabling-c-sharp-7-compilation-with-visual-studio-2017/ ?

Comment: Go to your project's properties and look at `Build => Advanced` and change the `Language version` to `C# 7.0`. That will cause a more explicit compile error on the build machine.

Comment: @Amy Yes, changing to Roslyn helped, it compiles now :)

Comment: Thanks for the lots of suggestions, I'll check the build server. @Amy, promote your comment to an answer, I'll accept that.

Comment: @Amy Just curious: I know how to change the language version like Matthew described, but where in VS is an explicit "use roselyn" option?

Comment: @RenéVogt "use roselyn" is advice for the online code tool.  In VS, you add the Nuget package "Microsoft.Net.Compilers".

Comment: The compiler seems to fail when trying to build the project via dotnet build with an error : MSB4801: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" is not supported on.  Is this using Roslyn by default or a different compiler?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You aren't using a compiler for C# 7. Change the compiler to Roslyn.

The key thing here is that the available language features are determined by the compiler, not the target framework.

Comment: The key thing here is that the available language features are determined by the *compiler*, not the target framework.  Perhaps you could add that to the answer?

Comment: How does one "Change the compiler to Roslyn"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int x;
if(int.TryParse(inputText, out x))
   StartAnotherMethod(x);
```

Comment: Yeah, I already knew that answer :) The intention was to use the new feature.

Answer (score 0):

It is compilation issue at build server.
I resolved it by dividing one statement into two as below.

int.TryParse(input, out int value);

Solution: 
**int value=0;
int.TryParse(input, out value);**

or you can change compiler at build server if you are allowed.

Comment: Soooo, _not_ using the C# 7 feature is the "solution"? :)